# Arrange one field in horizontal position

Tags: crystal-reports

My Crystal report outputs this:

```
 Date (dd/mm/yyyy)     Weight
   -----------------------------------------
    01-01-2013            6500
    02-01-2013            6500
    03-01-2013            11500
```

How can I group by Date in a horizontal way with one field? The output should look like:

```
01-01-2013 | 02-01-2013 | 03-01-2013
-----------|------------|---------
 6500      |  6500      |  11500
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a Cross-tab. That's Crystal's version of a grid or table. You can set this up easily in the wizard from `Insert > Cross-tab`.

Add it to your report, then right click it and select `Cross Tab Expert`. From there you can add your `Date` field as a column and `Weight` as a Summarized Field

Comment: But in cross tab we cant design customize as per we like.....is it right?

Comment: I dont want to use cross tab is there any other method?

Comment: @s.k.Soni There isn't any other good method. Why don't you want to use a Crosstab? It was designed for this exact scenario.

Comment: actually in crosstab which i want design that type of design is not be happing.

Comment: @s.k.Soni It's hard for me to understand you, but if you want to customize the Crosstab's visual appearance, you actually can. What design do you want to use?